# Nullpointer exception when starting the application server

Tags: intershop

After setting up my local development environment I got a nullpointer exception, immediately after starting up the Nodemanager:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
   at java.util.Hashtable.put(Hashtable.java:459)
   at java.util.Properties.setProperty(Properties.java:166)
   at com.intershop.beehive.tcm.event.MulticastPropertyMgrImpl.getProperties(MulticastPropertyMgrImpl.java:66)
   at com.intershop.beehive.tcm.event.EventMgrImpl.start(EventMgrImpl.java:100)
   at com.intershop.beehive.nodemanager.NodeManager.bootstrap(NodeManager.java:202)
   at com.intershop.beehive.nodemanager.NodeManager.main(NodeManager.java:102)
[NodeManager] [2017-10-03 13:23:34.530 +0200] ERROR [nodemanager]:
java.lang.NullPointerException
   at java.util.Hashtable.put(Hashtable.java:459)
   at java.util.Properties.setProperty(Properties.java:166)
   at com.intershop.beehive.tcm.event.MulticastPropertyMgrImpl.getProperties(MulticastPropertyMgrImpl.java:66)
   at com.intershop.beehive.tcm.event.EventMgrImpl.start(EventMgrImpl.java:100)
   at com.intershop.beehive.nodemanager.NodeManager.bootstrap(NodeManager.java:202)
   at com.intershop.beehive.nodemanager.NodeManager.main(NodeManager.java:102)
```

Comment: What is your question then?

Comment: No question, just to post a solution for other developers facing the same issue :)

Comment: You should post the solution below, in the answer section. :)

Comment: I've done that now, @Gianlucca

Comment: Awesome! And welcome to stackoverflow!

Answer (score 3):

I was able to solve this by:

- making sure the server folder (and all its subdirectories) has read/write access for 'Everyone'
- remove 'server\share\system\tcm\config\cluster.id' and 'server\share\system\config\cluster.id'

Now the application server starts up as normal